# Index of elements, jQuery or Javascript

Tags: jquery, indexing

I've a table that contains 3 columns. I need to bind an event that fires off whenever one of those columns is clicked using jQuery.

However, I need to know the index of the column clicked.

i.e: First column (index 0), Second column (index 1), Third column (index 2), and so on...

How can I do that?

var firstRow:

```
var firstRow = $("tr:first > th", "table[id*=Grid]");
```

Take a look:

```
firstrow.click(function(e){
//var id = e.target.index;
var id = $(e).parent().children().index(this);//returns -1
})
```

Comment: What's `firstrow`? the `<tr>`?  You need to capture the click on the `<td>`...a delegate function with `jQuery is the cleanest approach to do that.

Comment: firstrow,take all "<th>" elements of first row

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) (it's 0 based), like this:

```
$("td").click(function() {
  var i = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
  alert(i);
});
```

Comment: i dont think so,cause im trying to do this with function(e){}.i.e:
e.target.index

Comment: @ozsenegal - Which browser? It works in all tested here...can click the link to test for yourself.

Comment: @ozsenegal - You're using the *exact* code above?  Testing this: http://jsfiddle.net/F5ALE/ in FireFox 3.6.3 works here...

Comment: @ozsenegal - That changes the entire meaning :)  Is your function attached to the `<tr>` or the `<td>`?

Comment: function is attached to all "th" of the first row

Comment: @ozsenegal - Then you need to show how it's being attached, if you changed my exact code above and swapped `"th"` for `"td"` it would work.  Context is **everything** here, you need to show how the handler you're attaching is coded.

Comment: @ozsenegal - If you leave my example and don't change the `this` the code works with your updated answer still: http://jsfiddle.net/F5ALE/1/  `e` and `this` have **very** different meanings, they are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a better idea to use native javascripts `.rowIndex` instead of
jQuerys `.index`. jQuery might have some trouble in detecting table head (TH) elements.

Comment: How would you use `.rowIndex` to get the index of a column?

Comment: Should be `this.cellIndex`. But yes: much simpler and more efficient than making jQuery search a node list.

Comment: yes, within your click event handler code it is this.rowIndex() / this.cellIndex()

Answer (score 0):

I always liked using [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll)

```
$('table').click(function(e) {
  var $targ = $(e.target);
  if ($targ.is('th')) {
    var position = $targ.prevAll().length;
    alert(position);
  }
});
```

[Preview on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/idohu3)