# How to get the position of an element inside another element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I click on the 1st div I want to get either 0 or 1 and if the second div 2 and so on...

None of my attempts are working:

http://jsfiddle.net/DZh8k/

```
$('div').click(function() {

    //alert( $('#something').index($(this)) );
    //alert( $(this).index( $('#something') ) );
    console.log( $('#something').find($(this)).eq() );

});


<span id="something">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</span>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery index within a parent class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147021/jquery-index-within-a-parent-class) and [Index of elements, jQuery or Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2579897/218196) and potentially others.

Comment: Note that positioning `div` elements inside `span` is invalid HTML and they browser might correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `$(this).index()` will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/DZh8k/2/

Comment: Interesting, never knew that one. +1